# How can I disconnect a running Browsersync instance?

Tags: browser-sync

I often would like to compare a new change with the original.  To do this, I open two browser tabs of the same page, make a change, then reload one of the tabs to compare.  With Browsersync enabled, this becomes impossible because both tabs automatically reload.

How can I disable Browsersync for a particular tab to prevent this from happening?  I'm looking for a way to do this from the Javascript console, not having to stop/reload my watcher.

The Browsersync API has a pause() method, but I can't see a way to access this from an actual running Browsersync instance.  There is a `window.___browserSync___` object accessible, so there must be some way to achieve this.

Answer (score 9):

The command should be:

```
 window.___browserSync___.socket.disconnect();
```

If the `___browserSync___` object isn't available for some reason from the console try doing this in a fresh tab.